# Form type not found by Symfony - What did I miss?

Tags: forms, symfony, controller

Here is the error I get :

```
Fatal error: Class 'bnd\myBundle\Controller\pageApproachUpdateType' not found in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\bnd\myBundle\Controller\NTController.php on line 208
```

As if Symfony was looking for the wrong directory...

Yet, in the same NTController.php, I already have some code to call a form which works fine. I just copied/renamed/pasted those lines to match the right Type and Handler.

Here is an extract of the Controller/NTController.php :

```
public function pageApproachUpdateAction($pageId)
    {
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $page = $em->getRepository('bndmyBundle:Page')->find($pageId);
    $formNT = $this->createForm(new pageApproachUpdateType, $page);
    $formHandler = new pageApproachUpdateHandler($formNT, $this->get('request'), $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager());
    ----
    }
```

and an extract of the form type, Form/pageApproachUpdateType.php :

```
namespace bnd\myBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class pageApproachUpdateType extends AbstractType
{
---
}
```

I tried to clear the cache ; I just don't understant what I missed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the use statement for pageApproachUpdateType at the top of your NTController.php file:

```
use bnd\myBundle\Form\pageApproachUpdateType;
```